# Proving that a point on the boundary of a closed ball in a metric space cannot be interior.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The idea of this proof is quite clear but I'm having some trouble making it rigorous. Suppose we have a metric space $(X, d)$ and a closed ball $U := \{x \in X : d(x, a) \leq t\}$ for some fixed $a$ and $t$. I want to prove that a point on the boundary of this ball is not an interior point. Here is my "proof":

Let $x$ satisfy $d(x, a) = t$ (i.e. let $x$ be a boundary point). Suppose also that $x$ is interior. Then $\exists \, r > 0$ such that the open ball $D_r(x)$ is contained within $U$. This an immediate contradiction, because some points in this open ball are outside $U$.

My problem is with the very last statement, which relies entirely upon geometrical intuition and is not very rigorous. I suppose I could try a bit harder with this idea: along the line connecting $a$ and $x$, we can go a bit further along the line still inside the $r$ -ball and find a point outside of $U$. But this still doesn't sound very rigorous, with things like lines only really applying to Euclidean space.

How can I make this rigorous?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers and comments, I now realize that this cannot be proven at all.

Comment: You can't make it rigorous, because there are metric spaces where the set $\{ y : d(a,y) = t\}$ is contained in the interior of $\{ x : d(a,x) \leqslant t\}$.

Comment: What is your definition of the boundary of a set in a metric space?

Comment: @DanielFischer how is that possible? Maybe my intuitions are terribly off on these concepts. My definition of boundary is the closure - the interior; that is all points that are in the closure but not the interior.

Comment: Apart from the discrete space example mentioned in the comments on the answer (where that happens for _some_ values of $t$), there are also so-called ultrametric spaces, where the metric satisfies a stronger inequality than just the triangle inequality, namely $d(x,z) \leqslant \max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$. In such spaces, the "sphere" of radius $t$ is contained in the interior of the closed ball of radius $t$ for all $t > 0$. Yes, that is somewhat unintuitive, but unintuitive things happen a lot in topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general metric space the boundary of the set $U = \{x : d(x,a) \le t\}$ is not the set $\{x : d(x,a) = t\}$.

The (usual) definition of boundary point of a set implies that the boundary and interior of a set are disjoint.

Comment: ... and in fact in $\mathbb Z$ with standard metric, $1$ is on the what-you-might-mistake-for-boundary of the $1$-ball $\{-1,0,1\}$ around $0$ and yet is an interior point of it.

Comment: Really? What would the boundary be then? I thought for sure that the interior is just the open ball version of this set...am I wrong?

Comment: I see now where I went wrong. Thanks for that example with Z.